# Handling error RXJava with Throwable object

Tags: android, rx-java

I want to do an http call like this

```
Observable<CimaDeviceStatus> status = CimaComm.getInstance().getService().getDeviceStatus();
status.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()).map(result -> result).subscribe(this::onPaymentStatusUpdate, error -> handleCimaError(error));
```

the code works if the server answer 200, and i am able to read the body of the response

```
private void onPaymentStatusUpdate(CimaDeviceStatus cimaDeviceStatus) {
    ...
}
```

but when an error occured, `handleCimaError` is called, but i can't manage to read the body of the error since the argument is a Throwable, and not the object the server send

```
private void handleCimaError(Throwable throwable) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: have you tried `throwable.getMessage()` ?